# NVD3 javascript: apply color gradient in scatter plot for each group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, nvd3.js, scatter-plot

I'm trying to customize the nvd3 scatter plot chart provided [here][1]:

The example has 4 distinct colors for 4 groups. I have a continuous measure named proportion for each observation (between 0 and 1), that I would like to apply to the group colors to vary the shades. Values close to 0 would be a white fill (with the group's color as a border), while values of 1 would be the solid colors already used in the example. So for example, group 3 from the plot would have shades such as dark, medium, and light red, while group 2 would have different shades of green, group 2 would have different shades of orange, and group 1 have different shades of blue (with the value 0 being white for all 4 groups).

I know that you can use the color function to specify the colors, but can't seem to specify the gradient according to the group. Any advice would be really appreciated. thanks! Code example pasted below.

```
format = d3.format(",.2f");

//Format A
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
                .showDistX(true)
                .showDistY(true)
                //.height(500)
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  //Configure how the tooltip looks.
//  chart.tooltipContent(function(key) {
//      return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>';
//  });
  chart.tooltipContent(function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
     var d = e.series.values[e.pointIndex];
     return '<h3>' + e.series.key + '</h3><p>Size: ' + format(d.size) + '<br>Shape: ' + d.shape + '</p>';
  });

  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))

  var myData = randomData(4,40);
  d3.select('#test1 svg')
      .datum(myData)
      .transition().duration(500)
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});


function randomData(groups, points) { //# groups,# points per group
  var data = [],
      shapes = ['circle', 'cross', 'triangle-up', 'triangle-down', 'diamond', 'square'],
      random = d3.random.normal();

  for (i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
    data.push({
      key: 'Group ' + i,
      values: []
    });

    for (j = 0; j < points; j++) {
      data[i].values.push({
        x: random(),
        y: random(),
        size: Math.random(),
        proportion: Math.random(),
        shape: shapes[j % 6]
      });
    }
  }

  return data;
}
```